# Python Tornado Blocking in AsyncHTTPClient only on Linux. Not on windows or OSX

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, tornado

I'm getting very strange behavior from my Tornado AsyncHTTPClient client.

When I run the same code on Windows, OSX, Ubuntu, Redhat, and the Amazon AMI, my code behaves differently.

Here is the relevant code:

```
 request = HTTPRequest(self.URL,
                      method="POST",
                      auth_username=self.USERNAME,
                      auth_password=self.PASSWORD,
                      headers=self.HEADERS,
                      body=formatted_request
                      )
try:
  print "before", datetime.now()
  future = self.HTTP_CLIENT.fetch(request, self.handle_response)
  print "after", datetime.now()
```

On OSX and Winodws, the output of this code is (**Non blocking**):

```
before 2015-10-27 17:51:13.896538
after 2015-10-27 17:51:14.414656
before 2015-10-27 17:51:14.418626
after 2015-10-27 17:51:14.420233
before 2015-10-27 17:51:14.423062
after 2015-10-27 17:51:14.424126
before 2015-10-27 17:51:14.426491
after 2015-10-27 17:51:14.427542
before 2015-10-27 17:51:14.429675
after 2015-10-27 17:51:14.430702
before 2015-10-27 17:51:14.432825
after 2015-10-27 17:51:14.433863
```

On Ubuntu, Redhat, and the amazon AMI I am getting this (**a difference of 2 seconds in between what is supposed to be non blocking code**):

```
before 2015-10-27 21:49:23.644458
after 2015-10-27 21:49:25.541746
before 2015-10-27 21:49:25.542827
after 2015-10-27 21:49:27.428840
before 2015-10-27 21:49:27.429993
after 2015-10-27 21:49:29.326183
before 2015-10-27 21:49:29.327549
```

I noticed in the tornado code that there is a difference between linux and osx:

> We use `epoll` (Linux) or `kqueue` (BSD and Mac OS X) if they
>       are available, or else we fall back on select(). If you are
>       implementing a system that needs to handle thousands of
>       simultaneous connections, you should use a system that supports
>       either `epoll` or `kqueue`.

But the performance difference between the different platforms seems unlikely to be a epoll / kqueue issue.

I'm using python 2.7 and tornado 4.2.1. Distribution versions are the EC2 versions downloaded from the AWS instance start page.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is probably in the DNS resolution, which is blocking by default. When it's fast, you're getting a cached result, and when it's not you're going out to the original nameservers (and probably talking to a non-optimal resolver if it's taking 2 seconds).

Try installing the `futures` package and doing `tornado.netutil.Resolver.configure("tornado.netutil.ThreadedResolver")`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll take a look at that now.

Comment: That Worked. Thanks! Maybe add a note in the AsyncHTTPClient docs to say that it blocks on DNS to make it more clear? I saw that the docs mention this for the HttpClient, but it seems to be missing for the Async Docs: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/async.html#blocking.

Comment: We're still getting very strange behavior from tornado. We're using the async client (100 threads) / threaded resolver(300).

The total response time is 0.09 seconds for 1 request. When we send 2 requests the total time increases to 0.11. With 5 requests, the time is 0.13. With 10 requests, 0.36. 

When we send 1000 requests the fastest response is 0.5 seconds.

We'd love to steal your brain for an hour -- do you have a consulting rate? friedmanj98 at gmail

Thanks!